# Issue with showing a custom context menu

Tags: angular, typescript

Basically I have a custom context menu component and I want it to show when a user right clicks in a certain component.

I have implemented the basic functionality, passing the `ElementRef` to the context menu and adding an custom event handler to handle showing the context menu next to the cursor.

I can see that the event is being fired and the normal browser context menu is not opening due to `$event.preventDefault()`, but my context menu is not showing up as expected. The boolean should be set so that the `*ngIf` in the template evaluates to `true`.

Direct public accessors to the properties have brought me to the same result.

[Here is a stackblitz with the implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xaoxfm)

Answer (score 0):

To create dynamic components you need to talk to Angular https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver. 
Played around a bit with your Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wquakt

Btw I suggest to use some component for example
https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview

Comment: Thanks, this looks quite interesting. And yes, I will definitely use a menu component to implement the functionality of the context menu later.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the way that the name `this` is resolved. At the moment, when your `onContextMenu` method is called, `this` is *not* resolved to your `AppContextMenuComponent` class (as you might expect). To see this in action, try inserting `console.log(this)` somewhere within that method. Since `this` is not resolved as you might expect, the assignment statement `this._isOpen = true` is not doing what you'd like. One quick fix for this is to [explicitly "bind"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) a value that the name `this` should resolve to, by changing your event-listener setup to:

```
.addEventListener('contextmenu', this.onContextMenu.bind(this));
//                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However, this may lead to trouble when you wish to later remove this event listener. Others may have better solutions to this, but one option is to use an arrow function in place of your method (note that this relies on the ["class fields proposal"](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields), which is not part of ES6).

Here's what that change looks like:

```
private onContextMenu = ($event: MouseEvent): void => {
  //                  ^                            ^^
  // Body remains unchanged
};
```

Here's an [updated StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tx45gt?file=src/app/app-contextmenu/app-contextmenu.component.ts) with the change.

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much, I didn't check `this` sadly, so I really didn't know what was going on.