# Why is 'this' undefined in parent typescript class?

Tags: typescript, deno

Having the following class hierarchy in a Deno Typescript project:

**AccountPutController.ts**

```
export class AccountPutController extends HttpController {

    constructor(commandBus: CommandBus) {
        super(commandBus)
    }

    async handle({ params, request, response } : {
            params: { id: string }
            request: any
            response: any
        } 
    ) {
        const { value : requestBody } = await request.body()

        super.dispatch(
            new CreateAccountCommand(
                params.id,
                requestBody.username,
                requestBody.emailAddress,
                requestBody.password
            )
        )
        
        response.status = 201
    }

}
```

**HttpController.ts**

```
export abstract class HttpController {

    private readonly commandBus: CommandBus

    constructor(commandBus: CommandBus) {
        this.commandBus = commandBus
    }

    dispatch(command: Command) {
        if(this === undefined) {
            console.log("This is undefined")
            return
        }            
        this.commandBus.dispatch(command)
    }

}
```

The condition *"this === undefined"* evaluates true. Does anybody know why ? How can I prevent that?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61526053/13258211) help you? (Excuse the unintended pun)

Comment: why don't you use `this.dispatch(cmd)` instead of `super.dispatch(cmd)` ?

Comment: and are you sure ? i've created two dummy classes one extends the other and it works in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is determined when you're calling a function. How are you invoking your `handle` method?

Consider this example:

```
abstract class Abstract {
  dispatch() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

class Concrete extends Abstract {
  handle() {
    super.dispatch()
  }
}
```

If you do this, it works as expected:

```
new Concrete().handle(); // this === Concrete
```

If you do that, `this` will be `undefined`:

```
const { handle } = new Concrete();

handle(); // this === undefined
```